# ¿Se necesita algún tipo de permiso para REST?

Tags: rest, retrofit

Estoy haciendo un webservice REST, y lo estoy consumiendo desde android con retrofit, lo ensayo localmente y funciona bien, pero subo el webservice al servidor y cambio el BASE_URL en retrofit pero siempre me devuelve un "onFailure".

Utilizando postman me sale lo siguiente:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("7dc520c99c4693e0a16202bab8dbb114");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://ncategories.com/rest/login.php?api=12&emailUserName=j&password=1";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

Buscando info sobre este problema podría deberse a una implementación anti bots por parte del servidor(servidor gratuito).

REST PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../models/usersRest.php");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

$cat=new usersRest();

header('Content-Type: application/JSON');
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$responseNoFound = ["id"=>"-1",
"userName"=>"-1",
"email"=>"-1",
"password"=>"-1",
"status"=>"-1"];
$responseOne = array($responseNoFound);

switch ($method) {
case 'GET'://consulta
  $emailUserName=$_GET['emailUserName'];
  $passwd=$_GET['password'];
  $apiId=$_GET['api'];

if($apiId==$GLOBALS["rest_id"]){

  $cat=new usersRest();
  $r=$cat->loginRest($emailUserName,$passwd);

  if(count($r)>0){

    http_response_code(200);

    print_r (json_encode($r),false);
    }else{
        http_response_code(200);
        print_r (json_encode ($responseOne),false);
    }
    }else{
  }
break;
}
  ?>
```

el OnFailure da lo siguiente:

Failure Request{method=GET, url=http://ncategories.com/rest/login.php?api=12&emailUserName=j&password=1,tag=null}

Comment: Sí, tienes que habilitar en el REST los Cross Domain Request. Prueba con Postman el error que te da, porque probablemente sea eso.

Comment: Pero postman en ese sentido funciona como una app de servidor, no toma en cuenta las restricciones CORS me parece

Comment: ya puse lo que me sale en postman

Comment: No, postman en este caso es un cliente, pero, creo que tienes problemas para configurar el request. No puedes capturar los datos del "onFailure"?

Comment: Con que lenguaje hiciste el REST? y para que tengas una idea de los es CORS: http://www.formandome.es/javascript/cors-vs-jsonp-solicitudes-ajax-entre-dominios/

Comment: @JocksanCruz en php, ahí lo agregué, seguí este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string y agregue el header al retrofit y funciona, no se si sea la mejor opción, pero por ahora funciona

Comment: Creo que no estas dando bien la dirección de tus assets, ahí dice   <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>  y sin javascript no puede funcionar tu webservice ,

Comment: @M121 La dirección es correcta, y funciona desde el navegador, no se porqué desde android no, y ya agregué los CORS como menciona Jocksan Cruz